# Castle DynamicProxy automatic property initialization

Tags: castle, castle-dynamicproxy

I have the following interfaces:

```
interface IFoo {}
interface IBar {
    IFoo Foo {get;set;}
}
```

Given a generated proxy implementation

```
var generator = new ProxyGenerator();
var proxy = generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget<IBar>();
```

Is there a way to have the property `Foo` of `proxy` have its instance mocked **and** initialized such that

```
Assert.IsNotNull(proxy.Foo);
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The proxy wont have backing fields for the properties. Its sole purpose is to invoke the interceptor chain, so it's up on of your interceptors to return a value for the property.